# Tree presentation of XML structure - how to test for parents/preceding siblings inside recursion?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to represent an XML structure like a directory tree. It's a navigation editor, hence the element names links (the group), and link (the item within the group). So I have different images: i-node, l-node, t-node and e-node images (where e is empty the others are the dotted lines). The HTML is supposed to be a standard table. Each link is in its new tr.

So far, so good...

[image: so far so good]

But:

[image: here's the dealio]

In the first case the images are as expected but in the second one you see where I got stuck: as soon as there is an L node (last element on that level) all the subsequent links should show an empty-node image for that level - but instead there's an I-node right now.
So I'd need some advice on how to achieve this. Would I need to check the XML for its preceding siblings? Or can I do this by passing another parameter to the recursive call? Any help appreciated... I'd rather do it properly than starting to fix up the HTML with JS ;)

The XML:

```
<navigation>
  <links>
    <link>
       <text>Google</text>
       <links>
         <link>
           <text>Yahoo</text>
         </link>
         <link>
           <text>Amazon</text>
         </link>
       </links>
    </link>
    <link />
    <link />
    <link />
    ...
  </links>
</navigation>
```

The XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="navigation">
<table>
  <xsl:for-each select="links">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="level" select="'1'" />
          <xsl:with-param name="children" select="count(*[links/link])" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="links">
    <xsl:param name="level" />
    <xsl:param name="children" />
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(link)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="link">
        <tr>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">level<xsl:value-of select="$level" /></xsl:attribute>
            <td>
                <xsl:call-template name="nodeimage.loop">
                    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level"></xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="position()"></xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <strong><xsl:value-of select="text" /></strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- if a link has children... -->
        <xsl:if test="*[link]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="links">
                <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="children" select="count(*[link])"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nodeimage.loop">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <xsl:param name="position"/>
    <xsl:param name="count"/>

    <!-- debug this 
    <xsl:value-of select="$position" />of<xsl:value-of select="$count" />, level<xsl:value-of select="$level" />
    -->
    <xsl:if test="$level = 1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$position = $count"><!-- last one on same level -->
                <img class="textmiddle" src="/images/backend/l-node.png" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <img class="textmiddle" src="/images/backend/t-node.png" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$level &gt; 1">
        <img class="textmiddle" src="/images/backend/i-node.png" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$level &gt; 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="nodeimage.loop">
            <xsl:with-param name="level">
                <xsl:value-of select="$level - 1"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="position">
                <xsl:value-of select="$position"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These templates (written for XSLT 1.0) should be able to render your tree structure - they're not using recursion, but rather match-templates for processing the general structure, and then a moded template for the images (by processing each ancestor of the context node):

```
<xsl:template match="navigation">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <xsl:call-template name="headers" />
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="links" />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:variable name="chain" select="ancestor-or-self::link" />
    <tr class="level{count($chain)}">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$chain" mode="tracks">
                <xsl:with-param name="context" select="." />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <strong><xsl:value-of select="text" /></strong>
        </td>
        <td><button>Append new link</button></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="url" /></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="links" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link" mode="tracks">
    <xsl:param name="context" />
    <xsl:variable name="isSame" select="generate-id(.) = generate-id($context)" />
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(preceding-sibling::link)" />
    <xsl:variable name="isLast" select="not(following-sibling::link)" />
    <xsl:variable name="type">
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isSame">
            <xsl:if test="(following::link or links/link) and not($isLast)">t</xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$isLast">l</xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$isLast and links/link">e</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="following::link and links/link">i</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(following::link)">e</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="node-type">
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$type" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="node-type">
    <xsl:param name="type" select="'t'" />
    <img class="textmiddle" src="/images/backend/{$type}-node.png" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="headers">
    <tr>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>&#160;</th>
        <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note that applying templates to the `links` nodes will use a built-in template to subsequently process the `link` nodes if no template matches `links`.)